# keep n retention and delete old one

Tags: python, json, backup

I have the code below which looks for 2 keys and deletes the old one.  That means I only have one data-retention

```
def delete_old_snap(self, volumeid):
    list_snap = self.snapshots()

    def doubles(l):
        keys = [i["volume_id"] for i in l if i["volume_id"] == volumeid]
        keys = {k for k in keys if keys.count(k) > 1}
        return zip([[d for d in l if d["volume_id"] == k] for k in keys])

    for t in doubles(list_snap):
        snap_id_to_delete = t[0][0]['id'] if (
            t[0][0]['created_at'] < t[0][1]['created_at']
        ) else t[0][1]['id']
```

My goal is to allow for exemple 5 data-retentions like

```
def delete_old_snap(self, volumeid, retention=5):
    list_snap = self.snapshots()
    #keep retention keys (based on ['created_at'] )
    #loop for deleting the old one if found.
```

one sample of data:

```
[
{u'status': u'available', u'os-extended-snapshot-attributes:progress': u'100%', u'description': u'Daily snapshot',
 u'name': u'snap-DAILY-WEB-OCS_HOME', u'created_at': u'2015-01-22T14:09:30.000000',
 u'id': u'02ee7feb-6919-4732-9eb3-8c6f721dc426', u'volume_id': u'edcaac08-5f6a-4bf7-906c-d6ed9cb20b22', u'size': 2,
 u'os-extended-snapshot-attributes:project_id': u'a0998a6710f84dc78550393119b41721', u'metadata': {}},
 ....]
```

Comment: holy formatting batman

Comment: sorry, I'm not accustomed to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start by creating a dictionary where each key is a volume id

```
import dateutil.parser as p
d = {}
for snapshot in snapshots:
    snapshot["created_at"] = p.parse(snapshot["created_at"])
    try:
      d[snapshot["volume_id"]].append(snapshot)
    except KeyError:
      d[snapshot["volume_id"]]=[snapshot]
```

now you should be able to work with it much easier

```
from operator import itemgetter
d2 = {}
for volume,data_list in d.items():
    d2[volume] = sorted(data_list,key=itemgetter("created_at"),reverse=True)[:5]
```

d2 should now contain only the 5 most recent snampshots for any given volume

Comment: Hi @Joran , I implemented and it works as expected ( thanks a lot ), but I would like to understand. can you explain from line with p.parse 'til the except ? thanks